# How can I force an empty ConstraintLayout to fill its parent container?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using a `ConstraintLayout` as an overlay. It should be as wide and as tall as its parent container. However, for some strange reason it does not fill its parent vertically (but does horizontally). Here is the relevant XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  <-- This is the overlay
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With the above code the overlay is not visible either (its height is `0dp`). When I place a `TextView` inside, it expands to fit the `TextView`. In short, it is behaving as if its height was set to `wrap_content`.

How do I force it to fill its container while leaving it empty?

Comment: Instead of "match_parent" use "0dp" to match constraints

Comment: it should fill screen with match parent or 0dp. But the problem is color #80000000 is transparent code. I think thats why it looks like it expands to parent view.

Comment: @Pawel both don't work.

Comment: @BerkayKireçci the color doesn't matter. What is so weird is that it fills the screen in the Android Studio preview but not on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely your size specifications. From the [documentation for ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

There really should be a lint rule for this or *ConstraintLayout* should reject `match_parent`.